# Data model on online exam system

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am trying to implement online examination system.

There are two types of question, either fill in the blanks, or multiple choice questions (MCQs).

Right now, I modeled tables as:

```
questions (
    qid INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    question TEXT,
    answer VARCHAR(20),
    mcq TINYINT(1)
);

options (
    qid INT,
    options VARCHAR(20)
);
```

Options will be stored as:

```
{
    (1,option1),
    (1,option2),
    (1,option3),
    (1,option4)
}
```

MCQ is a 1-bit flag to flag whether it is MCQ or not, if yes, then it fetches options from options table.

1. For different courses in any institute, should I maintain  different table for different courses, **or add course field in question** table itself?
2. Is it okay to store answer in questions table, or should I maintain a separate answers table ?

   ```
   answers (
       qid INT,
       course VARCHAR(10),
       answer
   );
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For future additions etc. it is better to have a **course** table and refer to it in your questions table. This gives you flexibility when modifying your structure.
2. Again, for future additions you had better to have a separate **answer** table.

Your design can be like this:

[image: Sample ER Diagram]

Since it is a one-to-many relationship, there will be a `course_id` field in the question table.